# Is there a way to suppress the "Executing Function..." message during a ProgressOperation in Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a function in an IronPython script that loops through all DataTables and refreshes the ones that need refreshing, and I have this function wrapped in a ProgressOperation like in the code below. The only problem is, the status message keeps switching back and forth between saying "Gathering Data... Step x of y" to saying "Executing Function..." for a few seconds. I think it's because rather than doing some simple work inside the body of my loop, I'm calling the external function `ReloadLinkedData()` every time, and this is when it displays that it's executing a function. Is there a way to make it stop displaying "Executing Function..." and only show the status message?

```
stepCount = self.Document.Data.Tables.Count
with self.progress_service.CurrentProgress.BeginSubtask("Gathering Data...", stepCount, "Step {0} of {1}") as f:
    for dt in self.Document.Data.Tables:
        if (dt.NeedsRefresh):
            to_be_refreshed = List[DataTable]()
            to_be_refreshed.Add(dt)
            try:
                self.Document.Data.Tables.ReloadLinkedData(to_be_refreshed)
            except SystemError: # Error gets thrown if the table doesn't need to be refreshed
                pass
        self.progress_service.CurrentProgress.TryReportProgress()
        self.progress_service.CurrentProgress.CheckCancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Would putting the `ReloadLinkedData` outside the for loop correct the problem. It seems you would want your list built then all the refreshing to be done at once.

```
stepCount = self.Document.Data.Tables.Count
with self.progress_service.CurrentProgress.BeginSubtask("Gathering Data...", stepCount, "Step {0} of {1}") as f:
    for dt in self.Document.Data.Tables:
        self.progress_service.CurrentProgress.TryReportProgress()
        self.progress_service.CurrentProgress.CheckCancel()
        if (dt.NeedsRefresh):
            to_be_refreshed = List[DataTable]()
            to_be_refreshed.Add(dt)
    try:
        self.Document.Data.Tables.ReloadLinkedData(to_be_refreshed)
    except SystemError: # Error gets thrown if the table doesn't need to be refreshed
        pass
```

Comment: `to_be_refreshed` would need to be declared before the for loop starts. Even then, the problem is that the bottleneck in the process is refreshing the data, so that's what I'd like to see the determinate progress indicator for, so it can say "refreshing table 1 of 30".